# Django, PostgreSQL, Python3: how to use logarithm function

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, logarithm

I have `Post` table with something like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    likes = models.IntegerField()
    dislikes = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

I need to apply log function like this:
`log(max(abs(likes - dislikes), 1), 10)`

But I can't understand, how to connect raw SQL into Django query.

Comment: you could add a method to the model that does the computation using `self.likes` and `self.dislikes` with all operators you need. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I need to resolve logarithm function from raw sql expression into annotated field, because django doesn't have log function in python and it needs to be rawsqled.

Comment: For now I have 
Post.objects.annotate(
            score=F('likes') - F('dislikes')
        ).annotate(
            some_log=RawSQL('log(max(abs(score), 1),)', ())
        ) 
But it says column score doesnt exist, IDK how to resolve django's annotated value